# Move next line to current line after "+"

Tags: linux, awk, sed, tr

I have text file with data as you can see below

```
  1  0.751E-04  0.000E+00  0.113E-04  0.735E-05 -0.530E-05  0.410E-06 -0.805E-06      +
    -0.442E-06  0.476E-06 -0.252E-06
  2  0.792E-04  0.000E+00  0.134E-04  0.680E-05 -0.504E-05  0.435E-06 -0.895E-06      +
    -0.216E-06  0.149E-06 -0.133E-06
```

I want to move the line after + to the above or current line as shown below

```
  1  0.751E-04  0.000E+00  0.113E-04  0.735E-05 -0.530E-05  0.410E-06 -0.805E-06 -0.442E-06  0.476E-06 -0.252E-06
  2  0.792E-04  0.000E+00  0.134E-04  0.680E-05 -0.504E-05  0.435E-06 -0.895E-06 -0.216E-06  0.149E-06 -0.133E-06
```

I tried awk using below code

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /+/) print $0; getline; print}' A1.txt
```

With this code I get the output same as the input and the line/row is not moving  up.

I also tried tr

```
 tr '      +' ' ' < A1.txt >> ddg.txt
```

But got the same as output without the + sign.

I can share an example input file but I do not see an option here. Can I upload it in google drive  and share the link or would that be against the forum's rules?

Comment: `sed '/+$/ { N; s/+\n//; }'`

Comment: GNU sed: `sed -z 's/+\n//g'`

Comment: @jhnc sorry both your sugggestions are not working on my side.

Comment: @ash: dunno which OS you run to have all our commands to fails

Comment: Works with the sample input you provided. Won't work if your real input doesn't match that. eg. DOS line endings, or whitespace after the trailing `+`

Comment: @jhnc    that fixed the problem. dos line endings were the problem

Comment: Why don't you posted a response @jhnc?

Comment: @GillesQuénot In this case I already had solution but it just did not work. I am editing my files using winscp and it looks like its forcing my text files in linux to windows. I am trying to figure out why. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can your input have a line broken into more than two parts?

Comment: "sharing an example input file" here is generally expected to be done by reducing it to the minimum needed to show the issue and including that in the question (as you have already done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{gsub(/ +\+\n +/, " ")}1' file
```

With `GNU` [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -z 's/ \++\n \+/ /g' file
```

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\s+\+\n\s+/ /g' file
```

```
  1  0.751E-04  0.000E+00  0.113E-04  0.735E-05 -0.530E-05  0.410E-06 -0.805E-06 -0.442E-06  0.476E-06 -0.252E-06
  2  0.792E-04  0.000E+00  0.134E-04  0.680E-05 -0.504E-05  0.435E-06 -0.895E-06 -0.216E-06  0.149E-06 -0.133E-06
```

Comment: Sorry both codes did not work for me. I am still getting same input format as output.

Comment: Redhat 7.0 My output remains the same as it was in the input. I am not able to share the results here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (revised for \r\n line ending).  It will leave non-matching lines alone just in case:

```
$ sed '/ \{1,\}+\r$/{N; s/ \{1,\}+\r\n  //}' input.txt
  1  0.751E-04  0.000E+00  0.113E-04  0.735E-05 -0.530E-05  0.410E-06 -0.805E-06 -0.442E-06  0.476E-06 -0.252E-06
  2  0.792E-04  0.000E+00  0.134E-04  0.680E-05 -0.504E-05  0.435E-06 -0.895E-06 -0.216E-06  0.149E-06 -0.133E-06
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '
/^   /{
  sub(/[[:space:]]+\+/,"",val)
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
  print val,$0
  val=""
  next
}
/^  /{
  val=$0
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind an extra trailing newline ::

> ```
> awk $$ RS='[ +]+\n' ORS=' '
> ```

```
  1  0.751E-04  0.000E+00  0.113E-04  0.735E-05 -0.530E-05  0.410E-06 -0.805E-06     -0.442E-06  0.476E-06 -0.252E-06
  2  0.792E-04  0.000E+00  0.134E-04  0.680E-05 -0.504E-05  0.435E-06 -0.895E-06     -0.216E-06  0.149E-06 -0.133E-06
  3
```